# Is it possible to relay a WebSocket through NGINX over TLS?

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Can this:

- A node JS server acting as WebSocket client
- NGINX handling the WebSocket traffic
- JVM Socket Server

work over TLS?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood the question correctly, the JVM server establishes a Websocket connection, right?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I can imagine two ways to setup this:

1. Adding TLS to the Nginx
2. Adding TLS to the origin Websocket server (JVM in your case)

The second approach has more advantages because it secures the connection between Nginx and Websocket as well (imagine you want to host them in two different containers / machines)

Imagine a diagram like this for the first approach:

```
Nodejs Socket Client <--Secure--> Nginx <--NOT Secure--> JVM
```

and something like this for the second approach:

```
Nodejs Socket Client <--Secure--> Nginx <--Secure--> JVM
```

**I have created a public repository here which demonstrates how you can setup  the first approach: https://github.com/afshinm/websocket_tls_docker**

**Setup TLS on the server-side**

If you want to take the second approach, it varies from framework to framework. You'd need to read the documentations. But bear in mind, Nginx can decrypt and encrypt your traffic, so all you need to do in this case is changing the value of `proxy_pass` to `https://...` prefix so Nginx knows to decrypt the traffic first.

But for the first approach, just add following settings to your `server` configuration to enable TLS:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /path/ssl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/myserver.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

And don't forget to add these to your `server` or `location` block (according to your config):

```
proxy_pass ​http://your_jvm_backend_host;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
```

Now, you connection from Nginx to your clients is secure (`wss://...`).

**Setup client**

Assuming that you are using `ws` package, you can connect to the secure Websocket connection like this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://your_backend');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('Hola!');
});
```

That's it.

Comment: Super, thanks @afshin-mehrabani! Have you tried this out?

Comment: @Bod yes, I created a public repo here: https://github.com/afshinm/websocket_tls_docker